# How to use 'data-' props passed into a React class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following in my calling JSX component:

`<CoolThing data-itemx="Corduroy" data-itemy="Pancakes" />`

I want to be able to use these strings in my `CoolThing` class.

```
class CoolThing extends Component {
  getStyle() {
    var itemx = this.props.data-itemx;
    var itemy = this.props.data-itemy;
```

This produces `NaN` instead of the data strings. I've tried a few other things:

```
    this.props.dataItemx    // undefined
    this.props.dataitemx    // undefined
    this.props.itemx        // undefined
    this.props.data.itemx   // error accessing itemx of undefined
```

Running `console.log(this.props)` shows that `data-itemx` is present, but I can't access it.

I already read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html but it still isn't clear how to make this work.

So how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access it with the use of `brackets` notation, dot notation doesn't work with `-`

```
class CoolThing extends Component {
  getStyle() {
    var itemx = this.props['data-itemx'];
    var itemy = this.props['data-itemy'];
```

Snippet:

```js
class CoolThing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props['data-itemx']);
    return (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<CoolThing data-itemx="4324"/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Props` is an object, you are passing the values in props by keys: **data-itemx, data-itemy**

So those values will be available by the exact same name and use use brackets `[]` to access the values. Like this:

```
class CoolThing extends Component {
   getStyle() {
      var itemx = this.props['data-itemx'];
      var itemy = this.props['data-itemy'];
      console.log(itemx, itemy);
      ....
```

**Suggestion:** I will suggest you to not use **-** in properties name, use `dataItemx` and `dataItemy` instead of `data-itemx, data-itemy`.

Check this snippet:

```js
var App = (props) => {
   console.log(props['a-b'])
   return <p>Hello</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App a-b='a'/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```